# Instantiating template function in a false if constexpr gives error

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++, if-constexpr

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Params_t>
constexpr int constexprValue(Params_t...) { return 5; }

int main()
{
    const bool flag = true;

    if constexpr(flag)
    {
        constexpr int value = constexprValue(1, 2, 3);
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

This compiles and works fine. However, if `flag` is changed to `false`, then clang (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)) gives a compiler error:

```
error: constexpr variable 'value' must be initialized by a constant expression
undefined function 'constexprValue<int, int, int>' cannot be used in a constant expression
```

Is this a bug in clang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a bug it was fixed by this [commmit to clang: [Sema] Discarded statment should be an evaluatable context.](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/7cb94b0502fe0fbf58c5c6f213f1da9386c08034)  which has the following description:

> The constexpr evaluator was erroring out because these templates weren't
>   defined. Despite being used in a discarded statement, we still need to constexpr
>   evaluate them, which means that we need to instantiate them. Fixes PR37585.
>
> Differential revision: https://reviews.llvm.org/D48322

and includes the following test:

```
namespace PR37585 {
template <class T> struct S { static constexpr bool value = true; };
template <class T> constexpr bool f() { return true; }
template <class T> constexpr bool v = true;

void test() {
  if constexpr (true) {}
  else if constexpr (f<int>()) {}
  else if constexpr (S<int>::value) {}
  else if constexpr (v<int>) {}
}
}
```

If we try the test live [with godbolt with an older clang version](https://godbolt.org/z/QMwo7j) we obtain a very similar erroneous diagnostic that your example is seeing:

```
error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression
else if constexpr (f<int>()) {}
                   ^~~~~~~~

note: undefined function 'f<int>' cannot be used in a constant expression
```

the fix originated from [bug report: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression and std::is_same](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37585).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be a bug in the Apple version of clang, I'm able to compile the code with clang version 5 and greater as well as gcc version 7.1 and greater.

Matt Godbold has a great website for compiling snippets of code with a slew of different compilers.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/nWp2OU) is a link to your example in godbolt.